# how to import package in antlr4

Tags: antlr

I have two antlr4 files: "bar/Hello.g4" and "foo/Count.g4".

Now i want to import "Hello" in "Count" like this.

```
grammar Count;
import bar.Hello;
.....
```

And i got SYNTAX_ERROR: args=['.' came as a complete surprise to me] ...

How should i import Hello correctly???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this feature is still not supported currently.

[Antlr4 maven plugin cannot find grammar files in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089494/antlr4-maven-plugin-cannot-find-grammar-files-in-different-directories)