# How to import a grammar in Antlr4 when building with Maven?

Tags: maven, antlr

I'm trying to build an ANTLR project with Maven, the project structure is like

```
src/main +
      |-antlr4
             |-fo/bar
                   |-G1.g4
                   |-G2.g4
             |-imports
```

in which G1 imports G2 like:

```
grammar G1;
import G2;
```

However, when I build with Maven, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Message{errorType=CANNOT_FIND_IMPORTED_GRAMMAR, args=[G2, fo\bar\G1.g4], e=null, fileName='null', line=-1, charPosition=-1}
```

It works with no problem if I put `G1.g4` and `G2.g4` directly under `antlr4` directory. It seems to me that, when put the **Grammar** files in a package, it needs special syntax in the import statement.

I noticed the question [Antlr4 maven plugin cannot find grammar files in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089494/antlr4-maven-plugin-cannot-find-grammar-files-in-different-directories) , but here, the grammars are in **one** directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need the `G2.g4` grammar in the imports package (`src/main/antlr4/imports`), but you will have duplicated your grammar. To avoid this, change the import setting of the ANTLR plugin like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.1</version>
      <!-- vvv key part here vvv -->
      <configuration>
        <libDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/antlr4/fo/bar</libDirectory>
      </configuration>
      <!-- ^^^ key part here ^^^ -->
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>antlr4</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the configuration `libDirectory`.